# X and Y are independent iff $P(a < X \leq b, c < Y \leq d) = P(a < X \leq b) P(c < Y\leq d)$ proof

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

To phrase it another way, how would one show that these two expressions are equivalent?

1. $P(X \leq x, Y \leq y) = P(X \leq x) P (Y \leq y)$
2. $P(a < X \leq b, c < Y \leq d) = P(a < X \leq b) P(c < Y\leq d) \quad$ for all $a < b, c < d$

I tried to do it by writing the events as some sort of disjoint unions, but didn't really get anywhere. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is this not pretty much the definition of independence?

Answer (score 2):

Hint

If 2. holds

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X\leq x, Y\leq y)
&=\mathbb P(\bigcup_{n,m\geq 1}\{-n<X\leq x\}\cap\{ -m<Y\leq y\})
\\&=\lim_{n\to \infty }\lim_{m\to \infty }\mathbb P(-n<X\leq x, -m<Y\leq y)
\\&=\lim_{n\to \infty }\mathbb P(-n<X\leq x)\lim_{m\to \infty }\mathbb P(-m<Y\leq y)
\\&=\mathbb P(X\leq x)\mathbb P(Y\leq y).
\end{align}
$$

Conversely, if 1. holds, try a similar argument.